# Como pegar dados de um input, fazer um cálculo e jogar em outro input?

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como pegar um valor de um `input`, fazer o cálculo e jogar o resultado em outro `input`. Exemplo: `imc = peso x (altura)²`.E quando a pessoa colocar a altura e o peso nos `inputs`, o cálculo será feito e aparecerá no `input` do IMC.

Também tenho que realizar cálculos em outros campos, mas gostaria de uma ajuda pois não sei como fazer esses cálculos, se e em PHP mesmo ou JavaScript?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="pesoatual" placeholder="Peso Atual">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="altura" placeholder="Altura">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="number" name="idade" placeholder="Idade"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="date" name="datan" placeholder="Data de nascimento"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidab" placeholder="Medida do Braço" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidat" placeholder="Medida Tricipital" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidaabd" placeholder="Medida Abdominal" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="imc" placeholder="IMC" maxlength="4">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="gorduratricpital" placeholder="Gordura Tricipital" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciabraço" placeholder="Circunferência do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciambraço" placeholder="Circunferência Muscular do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Da pra fazer só em javascript sim. Da uma olhada nesse link: http://wbruno.com.br/javascript-puro/calculo-simples-entre-inputs-resposta-em-outro/ . E aqui o codigo funcionando: http://wbruno.com.br/examples/calc-simples/

Só adaptar para seus cálculos.

Comment: inclusive na net se vc pesquisar "calculo de imc em javascript" vc vai encontrar vários códigos prontos q tbm da pra vc adaptar, como esse por exemplo: http://www.emagrecerpravaler.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/calc.1-cod-html.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por serem valores que serão digitados, o recomendável usar JavaScript para fazer o cálculo. No entanto, a fórmula do imc na sua pergunta está incorreta. O correto é:

`imc = peso / (altura)²` e não <s>`imc = peso x (altura)²`</s>

> Fórmula: peso (em kg) dividido pelo quadrado da altura (em metros<sup>1</sup>).

Para jogar o valor do cálculo no campo `name="imc"`, pode usar `querySelector` para pegar os valores dos campos `name="pesoatual"` e `name="altura"` e atualizar o resultado de forma dinâmica à medida que os valores forem sendo inseridos nos campos:

```js
var peso = document.querySelector("input[name=pesoatual]");
var altu = document.querySelector("input[name=altura]");
peso.addEventListener("keyup", calcImc, false);
altu.addEventListener("keyup", calcImc, false);

function calcImc(){
   var peso_val = parseFloat(peso.value);
   var altu_val = altu.value;
   altu_val.match(/[,.]/) ? altu_val=parseFloat(altu_val.replace(",",".")) : altu_val=parseFloat(altu.value)/100;
   imc = (peso_val / (altu_val * altu_val)).toFixed(1); // "1" significa 1 casa decimal
   if(!isNaN(imc)){
      document.querySelector("input[name=imc]").value = imc;
   }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="pesoatual" placeholder="Peso Atual">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="altura" placeholder="Altura">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="number" name="idade" placeholder="Idade"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="date" name="datan" placeholder="Data de nascimento"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidab" placeholder="Medida do Braço" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidat" placeholder="Medida Tricipital" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidaabd" placeholder="Medida Abdominal" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="imc" placeholder="IMC" maxlength="4">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="gorduratricpital" placeholder="Gordura Tricipital" maxlength="5">
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciabraço" placeholder="Circunferência do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>

<div>
    <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciambraço" placeholder="Circunferência Muscular do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>
```

**<sup>1</sup>** Embora a [medida da altura oficial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice_de_massa_corporal) do cálculo do imc seja *metros*, para efeito de cálculo, o código acima também aceita valores em *centímetros*, o resultado será o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Da pra fazer com Javascript mesmo.

Segue exemplo bem simples https://jsfiddle.net/s9mn5nvf/

Espero que ajude.